# CTE over id, status, and date causing results to square

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE ItemDetail (
    ItemNumber        bigint not null,
    SiteId            int not null,
    Status            int not null,
    ScanDate          datetime not null,
)
```

What I am trying to do is get counts by site, by status, by day.  I have a CTE as defined

```
;WITH statCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Count(ItemNumber) over(partition by SiteId, Status, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ScanDate))) as ItemCount,
        SiteId,
        Status,
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ScanDate)) AS ScanDate
    FROM
        ItemDetail
)
```

The problem is that when I then run

```
select * from statCTE where siteid = 119 and scandate = '3/3/2011'
```

I get

```
ItemCount SiteId Status ScanDate
2   119 0   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
2   119 0   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
6   119 5   2011-03-03 00:00:00.000
```

The result set should be 2 rows, one with 2 for status 0 and one with 6 for status 6.  So, my partition isn't working with transforming the date into just a date object and picking the results.   I could just square root the `ItemCount` totals in my final query (a pivot), but that's more of a hack than fixing the actual problem.

Comment: Your CTE is still going to have one row for each row in ItemDetail.  See Example B on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstaning the use of Window functions (or ranking functions). In Your case Count is NOT an aggregate. This use add the result of the function to EVERY row returned by the query. Normally the aggregate is processed BEFORE the select clause, however in this example it is processes ALONG select clause. So TSQL counts how many rows satisfy Your partition and output it along EVERY row returned by the query.

You have 2 partitions with respectable count of 2 and 6 (calculated by the window partition function) and then whole result set is appended with additional column.

If You want the 2 and 6 results YOu need to write the query using the group by clause

```
WITH statCTE AS (
    SELECT
        Count(ItemNumber)as ItemCount,
        SiteId,
        Status,
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ScanDate)) AS ScanDate
    FROM
        ItemDetail
    group by  SiteId, Status, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ScanDate))
)
```